# delete rows with different dates in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL table in which every row contains a 'Date' value. I want to delete all the rows where the date is unequal to the current date.
I tried using the following lines to do so:

```
date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM " + League + " WHERE Date != " + "'" + date + "'")
```

It runs fine, but it doesn't actually delete any rows, even though I am sure there are rows with different dates. How can I delete these rows?

Comment: sql not equal is `<>` if I am not wrong, also you need to `commit` the transaction, also don't use string concatenation, it is prone to SQL injection

Comment: @Epsi95 Simply adding a commit statement worked. Thank you! How would you get rid of the concatenation? I have this right now: ` mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE Date <> %s", (League, Date)) ` But it gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to be fine. What is `League`? Hope it's a variable for your table name! Also, use bind variables and avoid using string concatenations.

```
date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(date)

conn = database.create_db_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "DELETE FROM test WHERE date != %s"
cursor.execute(query, date)
conn.commit()
```